# XeLatex under Ubuntu

Tags: xetex, ubuntu

I want to setup the `XeLaTeX` option to run some tex source files, however it is not listed where it should be. 
I am using `TexLive` (last version) with `TexMaker` on Ubuntu Desktop 12.10.
Or is this option available only if I run `TexLive` on Windows ?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59078/47522

Answer (score 92, accepted):

XeLatex is a part of `texlive-xetex` package.

To install, run the following command:
`sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex`

To use it use the following command:
`xelatex yourFilename.tex`

Comment: What if I have `TeXLive` already. How can I install `XeLaTeX` specifically?

Comment: @Royi `xetex` is not included in `texlive` package. It needs to installed separately.

Comment: Thank you! I added this info to my answer here: [Stack Overflow: pandoc: xelatex not found. xelatex is needed for pdf output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71609094/4561887)